# How to compare two directories in GitHub?

Tags: github, git-diff

I've found myself in a position where there are too many files/commits in my `develop` branch. I want to run a compare against `master` on GitHub, but I've reached the max commit/file counts that GitHub supports.

Is there a way in GitHub's UI to compare only a specific directory between my `develop` and `master` branches?

The logic is that I can ignore my `/vendors/` directory, and just compare my ~10 directories one at a time to look over the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Considering a very large commit, like [git/git/commit/deb00029a026ccb72b8abd27231ab1f98c9c268b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/deb00029a026ccb72b8abd27231ab1f98c9c268b), I tried and add `#diff-trace2` to jump directly to the `trace2` folder diff.

It did not work. Only [#diff-0a22feb83afbffdc3368ba4e3b005056b4efb51fef65131899f76ce885f71dd9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/deb00029a026ccb72b8abd27231ab1f98c9c268b#diff-0a22feb83afbffdc3368ba4e3b005056b4efb51fef65131899f76ce885f71dd9) would work (leave the page 5 to 10 seconds to shift to the right file), with `0a22feb83afbffdc3368ba4e3b005056b4efb51fef65131899f76ce885f71dd9` a file tree item in SHA256, which is not trivial to compute. And all Git 2.41 commands would still output SHA1 anyway.

That being said, the recent (July 2023) [Accessibility considerations behind code search and code view / Tree navigation](https://github.blog/2023-07-06-accessibility-considerations-behind-code-search-and-code-view/#tree-navigation), which uses those SHA256 values, might prove more robust and display more than the 2018 diff view. The large commit I mention at the beginning seems to be displayed lazily, with only the right set of files expanded when you navigate to the expected folder.

If not, a local clone and `git diff master..develop -- directory1/` remains the best option for large commits which are not correctly displayed by GitHub.